# Master/ Detail Form using Datagridviewcontrol (DevExpress) in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I need to create Master/Detail Form having (Dev Express) `Datagridviewcontrol` in VB.Net, that should have `Insert`, `update` and `delete` function.

Currently, I have developed a master/detail form that is working well upto data display, but I want to add three events for both master and detail (`Insert`, `Update` and `Delete`)

Answer (score 1):

You can find comprehensive information on the DevExpress documentation page for DataGrid [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3455)

From my experience with DevExpress controls, these editors support in-place editing and management of data supporting all CRUD operations, so it shouldn't be a problem for you to find a simple example and go step by step until you apply the same settings to your code.

This [list of examples and documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3078) can be a good starting point.

Comment: I have searched out more but fail to find solution. can you refer me any code/example  link?

Comment: I have updated my answer with link to the page that contains examples.